# What are lead/lag parameters in MATLAB movavg function?

Tags: matlab, moving-average

The syntax of **movavg** function in MATLAB is described below:

```
[Short, Long] = movavg(Asset, Lead, Lag, Alpha)
```

where **Lead** is Number of samples to use in **leading average calculation**, and **Lag** is Number of samples to use in the **lagging average calculation**. Please can you explain what do leading/lagging average calculation mean? It would be appreciated with an example.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation of [movavg](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/movavg.html)

Comment: [This might be useful](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1190-movavg-function-lead-and-lag-meaning)